Limit a user/role to not see the list of other users through snow sight - Users and Role section
Is there a way we can limit a user or a role to not see the list of other users through snow sight - Users and Role section.
Also, is there a way we can limit user to not have Public Role and only have the assigned Role displayed in his/her account ?

Public role is automatically granted to a user it cannot be revoked, if you want some object not to have public access then you can restrict public role to the objects.
